# In a QGIS plugin, how to let user click on canvas multiple times and store coordinates of all the points in a single list?

Tags: qgis-3, point, pyqgis-3, vector-layer, pyqt5

I am trying to get a list of coordinates for 3 different points in a single list. I am able to make a list of coordinates of a single point and then it overwrites the previous one while clicking to get the next point. Declaring an empty list every time is a problem but not getting correct logic anyway. Code is below.

```py
class PointTool(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):

    canvasClicked = pyqtSignal('QgsPointXY')
    def canvasPressEvent(self, event: QgsMapMouseEvent):
        crs_canvas = self.canvas().mapSettings().destinationCrs()
        xformer = QgsCoordinateTransform(crs_canvas, WGS, QgsProject.instance())
        point_clicked = event.mapPoint()
        point_wgs = xformer.transform(point_clicked)
        self.canvasClicked.emit(point_wgs)
    
   def activate(self):
        QApplication.setOverrideCursor(CUSTOM_CURSOR)   

class CurveTool:
    def _on_map_click(self): 
        self.point_tool = PointTool(self.iface.mapCanvas())
        self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(self.point_tool)
        self.point_tool.canvasClicked.connect(self._write_line_widget)
    def _write_line_widget(self, point: QgsPointXY):
        coords=[]
        coords.append(point.y())
        coords.append(point.x())
        self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(str(coords))
        self.iface.mapCanvas().unsetMapTool(self.point_tool)
        self.dlg.show()
```

In `coords`, I want coordinates of 3 consecutive clicked points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you are overwriting the list every time the function is called. It should be something like this:

```py
class CurveTool:
    coords = []    # store the coordinates outside the function
    clicks = 0     # have a way to count the clicks
    def _on_map_click(self): 
        self.point_tool = PointTool(self.iface.mapCanvas())
        self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(self.point_tool)
        self.point_tool.canvasClicked.connect(self._write_line_widget)
    def _write_line_widget(self, point: QgsPointXY):
        self.clicks += 1        # increment the click counter
        if self.clicks > 3:     # more than 3 clicks clears the list and resets the counter
            self.coords = []
            self.clicks = 0
        self.coords.append(point.y())
        self.coords.append(point.x())
        self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(str(coords))
        self.iface.mapCanvas().unsetMapTool(self.point_tool)
        self.dlg.show()
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt it helped. I was not aware of method to count clicks. It changed the direction of coding.